# Android - Speed up android.view.gles20canvas.drawdisplaylist

Tags: android

Screenshot of my traceview:

[image]

From what I understand, this is caused by having a lot of views on the screen and the device drawing a bunch.

I am not actively drawing a lot however, but I do have a lot of Rect's on the screen (650 tops, 600 min.).

How could I speed this up so that I don't get the lag I see?

If you need other data, please ask.